# how to use a variable sent from registerJs fnction in external js file in YII2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I want to implement a php array inside of external js page.
this is my *moarrefi.php* page:

```
$shakhe = Moarrefi::find()->all();
$name = ArrayHelper::toArray($shakhe);
$name  = json_encode($name);

$this->registerJs("
  var array = $name ;
", View::POS_HEAD);
```

and inside of *moarrefi.js*:

```
 console.log(array);
```

the problem is :
1- as i know yii uses jquery at the end of document and when i use  POS_HEAD 
i got this error from fireBug :

```
  ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

2- when i use POS_READY i got this error because external js uses array before declaring it:

```
  array is not defined
```

Now how can I use array in my external JS file.

Comment: declare the variable in top globally

Comment: @JYoThI top of where?

Comment: <script>  var array1 = <?php echo $name; ?> <script> like this and avoid using keyword so use array1 like this

Comment: @JYoThI i want to use pure YII2 functions and not <script> tag and moarrefi.php is a widget not view file

Comment: You shouldn't get the first error, since you don't use `$`.